# Best way to extend a particular section in JSF multilevel template

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a multi level JSF template, say layout.xhtml, which extends from number of template which is depicted below.

layout.xhtml -> level3.xhtml -> level2.xhtml ->level1.xhtml

How to extend **level1.xhtml** and **add one extra facelets ( I want 2 facelets overall) say customer-data.xhtml** and **supplier-data.xhtml** ) inherited from level1.xhtml in place of *navigation-module*, and have all the facelets of layout.xhtml too?

Below is my **template/level1.xhtml**

```
<ui:composition
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

            <ui:insert name="navigation-module" />
            <ui:insert name="time-module" />

</ui:composition>
```

I want to get the common template i.e. layout.xhtml I am not getting how to do this.

Comment: Please do let me know your suggestions. And also please let me know if there is any another way to achieve it.

Comment: I get the impression you want to see/have all pieces of the templates you inhert from visible when editing a page? This is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you want to add two pages for the navigation-module. Its very easy, just do the below

```
<ui:composition
        template=template/layout.xhtml
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

<ui:define name="navigation-module">
            <ui:insert name="WEB-INF/customer-data.xhtml" />
            <ui:insert name="WEB-INF/supplier-data.xhtml" />
</ui:define>
```

As long as you provide the correct `ui:insert` name i.e. in your case it is `navigation-module`, and in your ui:define you are telling to JSF, please insert these pages in place of navigation-module. Two keypoints to note here are

1. Make sure you mention your template name i.e. you can see immediate after ui:composition tag, i.e. template/layout.xhtml ( the reason being you want all the template features)
2. Use the exact name you want to override in `ui:define` i.e. in your case it is navigation-module

I hope I am clear to you. Incase you need any further clarification please feel free to drop a comment.